How to write a factory method for classes with an implicitly deleted copy constructor
TheClass contains a std::mutex (and many other members).
I want to write a function which creates this class so I only have to set the constructor arguments in one place:
TheClass CreateTheClassInstance()
{
    TheClass tc("specific args", specific_int);
    return tc;
}

then other classes requiring an instance of TheClass can call CreateTheClassInstance() to obtain one:
SomethingElse() : _the_class(CreateTheClassInstance())
{
}

TheClass _the_class;

Unfortunately because TheClass has a std::mutex, member CreateTheClassInstance() won't compile because the copy constructor is implicitly deleted.
I tried using std::move() but that too doesn't work.
Is there any other way I can achieve a factory method?

Details of class design is kind of important, it's not just mutex. The mutex itself you can hide in unique_ptr, or write a copiable/movable wrapper. You can also have a private move ctor for TheClass and make CreateTheClassInstance a friend.

std::unique_ptr<TheClass> CreateTheClassInstance() { /*...*/ }

@Gene hiding the mutex in a UP didn't work because I have a destructor and for some reason that kept the error message. However, the other comment has worked.

Wouldn't simply changing TheClass tc("specific args", specific_int); return tc; to return TheClass("specific args", specific_int); invoke guaranteed copy elision on C++17 and higher and avoid the use of a copy/move constructor? I think the initialization of _the_class as shown is also subject to guaranteed copy elision as well.

Also, if things get even more complex, the factory could return a smartpointer -- this basically lets receivers do whatever they want with the pointer, while the object itself doesn't move around at all

If you can compile as C++17 or higher, you should be able to support your specific use case by reorganizing your factory method to guarantee copy elision. It just requires that you directly return the new object without naming it, changing:
TheClass CreateTheClassInstance()
{
    TheClass tc("specific args", specific_int);  // Bad: Naming it means no guaranteed copy elision
    return tc;
}

to:
TheClass CreateTheClassInstance()
{
    return TheClass("specific args", specific_int);  // Good, we returned an unnamed instance created as part of the return, so guaranteed copy elision applies
}

The suggested use for initializing a member attribute SomethingElse() : _the_class(CreateTheClassInstance()) should also trigger guaranteed copy elision, leading to _the_class being directly initialized with no copies or moves at all.

In general, you don't want a class that uses mutex to be copiable/movable, because it protects some data when invariant is broken while functions are executed, and at that point creating copy or move would be an error.
But if you only want to use it in a factory function then making a private move/copy ctor and making factory function a friend can be a solution. To avoid writing code to move/copy all members of the class, you can wrap mutex itself to enable copy/move. Here is an example,
#include <mutex>

template<class Mutex>
struct mutexer : Mutex
{
    mutexer() = default;
    mutexer(const mutexer&) {}
    auto& operator= (const mutexer&) { return *this; }
};

struct TheClass;
TheClass CreateTheClassInstance(auto&& ... args);

struct TheClass
{
    TheClass(const char* str, int i) : _str(str), _i(i) {}
    // all other functions
private:
    const char* _str;
    int _i;
    mutexer<std::mutex> _m;
    TheClass(const TheClass&) = default;
    
    friend TheClass CreateTheClassInstance(auto&& ... args)
    {
        return TheClass(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto the_class = CreateTheClassInstance("123", 123);
}

Compiler Explorer demo
